# Hatcher and "house with two rooms"

Tags: algebraic-topology

On page 4 of Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" he constructs the "house with two rooms" space. He claims that there is some neighborhood containing this space that is homeomorphic to the unit ball (in $\mathbb{R}^3$). I was hoping someone would demonstrate how to prove this.

Comment: You might appreciate [this blog post](https://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/bings-house/) with lots of great pictures.

Comment: I had referred to the website Mike cited when I was taking topology. You can literally draw step by step sketches to obtain a ball. Collect the rooms to their respective entries and then pull their boundaries out (via their entries). Or you are looking for a more rigorous proof perhaps?